# jboss searchable cache

Tags: caching, jboss, searchable

I have jboss eap 5.1 and I am using struts 1.1 in it.Jdk is 1.6. Can it be used with the jboss searchable cache?How much memory can be stored in jboss searchable cache?I want to create google search type on type page load for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to create a searchable page and in order to answer your question appropriately, it will be good to understand what is that you are looking to search?

Are you searching among the objects stored in memory or are you searching among the rows in a database or are your searching a file system?

The fact that you mentioned [JBossSearchableCache](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossCacheSearchable) makes me believe that you might be searching among the objects in memory.

If that is the case, you can only store as much memory as is allocated to your JVM. For example: If your JVM has 1GB allocated you'll have approximately 1GB minus what your runtime needs. If you need more memory then you should consider a Data Grid like [Infinispan](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossCacheSearchable) where you can store all the data in memory in a grid that's highly available and also give you MapReduce capabilities. You can also use [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html) to write SQL type of queries that span the entire grid.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: I will be using standalone cache as i dont have any added infrastructure at this stage.Considering that:- (1.) How much memory of jvm can be configured max.I have 1 gb min and 2 gb max.can it be increase to 2 gb and 4 gb? (2.)How much of the memory percentage wise can be allocated for storing data like 200Mb out of 1gb? (3.) Out of ehache,jboss cache,swarm cache,infinispan:- which suits the storing of search results of total 50 Mb(1000 customer data *50 kb) of text data.Which means hashmap of 1000 customers as key and each having 50 Kb of string data.

Comment: You can configure as much memory as you have/need. Yes it can be increased easily through command line options (-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m). Memory storage is used by JVM to store objects. You can store as many objects as JVM can store. Any cache is good for simple use cases. If you have more complex requirements each of these caches offer different set of features.

Comment: How much of max memory can a jvm support.can i increase till 2 gb min and 4 gb max.Is there any statistics how much amount of data can be stored in jvm memory?

Comment: JVM can support any amount as long as your OS can provide it. On a 32-bit machine you are obviously limited but on a 64-bit you can provide as much as you can. There are some implications when you provide large memory pool (like 64G for example) w.r.t garbage collection but really there is no limitation from the JVM perspective on how much you can allocate.

Comment: Which cache supports disk store considering that the memory needed can exceed the RAM memory.I tried ehcache but that doesnt support search with diskstore.does infinispan support disk store and allow searching API?

Comment: Pretty much all the popular once do. I have used Infinispan and it does overflow to a disc.

Comment: I want to store 500 Mb in cache.Will infinispan work well with Quering data stored on disk and memory both? Performance wise does it work better than database when it is stored partially on disk?can you paste the code that you used in infinispan here?